# Pipe data to string Google Node API

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using the Google API Node client to download a pdf from my google drive, but I cannot figure out how to access the data coming in from the `service.files.get` function. My code is as follows:

```
function download(auth, fileId) {
    var service = google.drive('v3');
    var dest   = fs.createWriteStream('something.pdf');

    service.files.get({
        auth: auth,
        fileId: fileId,
        alt: 'media'
    })
    .on('data', function(chunk){
    console.log(chunk.toString()); // this gives me a JSON response of my bearer token, and not the pdf data
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        console.log('Done');
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Error during download', err);
    })
    .pipe(dest);
}
```

I am using this download to send an attachment via email. I don't want to save the file to my disk via the `dest` variable, and instead, would prefer to return a base64 encoded string from the `download` function but I am unable to access the incoming data from the API request. Could anyone point me to the right destination to accessing this?

The file downloads fine if I run the code as is, but I cannot figure out where the .pdf data is being streamed in from or how to access its 'data' event.

Answer (score 2):

Try accumulating the chunks of the response body into a variable in closure. You can access the complete accumulation in an 'end' event callback. I have also provided an example of returning the string from your async function via a callback that is provided to your download function. Note, you could do this with promises/async/etc., instead. The Node.js 'Stream' documentation for 'Stream Consumers' is particularly relevant (https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v5.x/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_consumers).

```
function download(auth, fileId, doneCb) {
  var respData = '';
  var service = google.drive('v3');

  service.files.get({
    auth: auth,
    fileId: fileId,
    alt: 'media'
  })
  .on('data', function(chunk) {
    respData += chunk;
  })
  .on('end', function () {
    // respData should contain all of the data now
    doneCb(respData);
  })
  .on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Error during download', err);
  });
}
```

Comment: When I do this I am still only getting a JSON object containing my authentication token and I am not sure why. The file downloads fine but for some reason I cannot access the data. Could the google api be doing something strange and not providing access to this info?

Comment: After looking at Google Node.js API client quick-start docs, looks like you don't need any streaming management. You should be able to access the file as the second argument passed to the callback triggered after completion. 
service.files.get({...}, function(err, resp) { resp.resource...})

Specifying request body

'The body of the request is specified in the resource parameter object of the request.' (https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#usage)

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: Clark you are indeed right, but the data is not passed through resp.resource as you have mentioned. I believe that is only for requests. See my answer above. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After digging through the API issues on GitHub, I discovered how to get the download response data. This is through a second parameter passed to the function which gives you the response data. I am able to pass the data back with a promise or a callback as follows:

```
service.files.get({
    auth: auth,
    fileId: fileId,
    alt: 'media'
}, {
    encoding: null // make sure that we get the binary data
}, function (err, buffer) {
    // I wrap this in a promise to handle the data
    if (err) reject(err);
    else resolve(buffer);
});
```